# I am not able to make regex for the following String

Tags: java, regex, string

/topics/computers.

In the above string I want to eliminate /topic/ and get the computers using regex. I tried [^/topics/]\w* and in this I am not able to get the words start with characters 't', 'o' , 'p', 'i', 'c'.Below I attached my code in java

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\/topics\\/]\\w+[a-z,A-Z]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Url);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            Url = matcher.group();
        }
```

Comment: Why not `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1)`?

Comment: Or `str.replace("/topic/", "")`

Comment: I can try that thanx